# How to set the minimum block length for duplicated blocks in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

Some of the SonarQube rules make sense, but have settings that don't work for all use cases and need to be configured accordingly. One of these is `common-java:DuplicatedBlocks`: 10 lines are too little for Java files, we are getting a lot of false positives.

However as opposed to many other rules, there is no configuration possible in the rule overview. Maybe because it's no "real" rule but just a placeholder.

**Administration -> General Settings -> Analysis Scope** has a section about duplications, but no way to configure the minimum block length. The issues section only lets me disable entire rules.

It seemes to me the block length could / should be configurable. But I can't seem to figure out how to change the settings.

How do I configure the block length of duplicated blocks in SonarQube?

Comment: As you've deduced, this configuration is not possible.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Can it be made configurable?